# Bathroom fan/light switch with outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, receptacle

I have a switch in my bathroom that controls both the fan and the light, and also has an outlet. Can I get anything that has two switches (one for the light and fan) and also not lose the outlet without having to drill and make space for an additional box?

[image: http://goo.gl/OPDQJk]

Comment: Are there separate wires in the switch box for the fan and light? If not, you'll have to run an additional wire/cable. I've never seen a GFCI double switch combination device, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist. However, since it sounds like you're just looking for a device, this question may be closed as a "shop for me" type question.

Comment: Apologies.  Didn't mean for this to be a shopping question.  What I really would like to do is install separate switches for the light fixtures and fan but not lose the outlet.  Here are pictures that I took of the receptacle itself. http://goo.gl/YZxPsB http://goo.gl/6vfwnz http://goo.gl/jtc52y http://goo.gl/DjJvpb

Comment: I can't tell from the photos how the switch connects to the light/fan. You should investigate how the two wires coming out of the top of the device are connected. It looks like one connects to the incoming feed and a pigtail to the receptacle, but I can't really see how the other one is connected. I do see a hint of a red wire in the back of the box, so there is hope that there's a separate wire for the light and the fan.

Comment: If you want to keep the outlet, the best thing you can do is replace the existing box with a double or triple box. You would have to cut into the tile a bit to make it happen, but with care you could do it without having to replace any of it.

Answer (score 2):

As Reece notes, you may have to pull another wire but in fact they do make these.

Combination Double Switch/GFCI Outlet: ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001N2Y3JI))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is already wiring to allow the separation of the fan and light from the same switch (ie.   L/F===|sw|==[+]--), then no - you will need to run a second [+] wire from the switch to the fan or light because the current circuit would look like L/F>---|sw|---[+]--.
If the circuit is like my first pictorial, then yes - it's just a matter of finding the right switch panel.